# Binomial Conditional Probability of a an event

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, conditional-probability

### Determining Binomial Condition Probability of a Random Sample

I have a question about binomial probability involving a conditional event. This problem keeps tripping me up, because while I know how to calculate the binomial probability that a random variable is a failure, i don't know how to calculate the conditional probability of that variable.

---

My question is as follows:

**70%** of the total shipments come from **factory A**, of which **10% are defective**.

**30%** of the total shipments come from **factory B**, of which **5% are defective**.

A random shipment comes in, and a sample of 20 pints is taken, and 1 of the pints is defective.

*What is the probability that this shipment came from the Factory A?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit 1**: didn't pay attention to the question. Will edit answer later today.

**Edit 2**: I've attempted to provide an answer below, however I might be mistaken. Feel free to correct me if I am in error.

$P(1 defective|A) \approx 0.270 \wedge P(1 defective|B) \approx 0.377 \\
P(A) = 0.7 \wedge P(B) = 0.3 \\
P(1D) = 0.7*0.270+0.3*0.377 = 0.189+0.113 = 0.302 \\
P(A|1D) = P(1D|A)*P(A)/P(1D)=0.270*0.7/0.302 \approx 0.626$

Comment: Just one pint out of 20 is defective.

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't notice that. Will have to update the answer when I get home. Thanks for noticing.